# JS - Disable Eventlistener once input field is selected

Tags: javascript

I'm currently adding a EventListener to my document. Which works great using the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) 
{
    if(event.keyCode === 68){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'right', state: true});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 83){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'down', state: true});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 65){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'left', state: true});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 87){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'up', state: true});
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) 
{
    if(event.keyCode === 68){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'right', state: false});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 83){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'down', state: false});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 65){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'left', state: false});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 87){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'up', state: false});
    }
});
```

But once I would select a input field and type something containing W, A, S, D then the EventListener would be triggered.

Is there a way to disable the eventListener once the input field is selected?

Comment: How about checking for focus inside the keyup/keydown listeners? Perhaps adding a class like `.ignoreInput` which you can add to elements, then check if the currently focused element has that class with something like `document.activeElement` (Assuming you want the listeners to start working again once the input is blurred)

Comment: `input.addEventListener('focus', function() { document.removeEventListener('keydown'....`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes check what [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is, if it is your input element just do a return, if not then let the code continue on.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if(event.target === someReferenceToYourElement){
     return;
  }
  //rest of code
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. This way you can check if the target is an input element and return so you don't need to know anything about the input elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable event bubbling from input. Something like this:

```
input.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {

  e.stopPropagation();

}, false);
input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {

  e.stopPropagation();

}, false);
```

So using code above you will disable `keyup` and `keydown` event bubbling and no one parent node of the input will not hear these events

Comment: This please my requirements. I need to disable many eventlistener if input selected. Just a question, what if we still want to enable one listener but disable others?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener on the focus of the input.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    e.StopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to do something like that:

```
$('document').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 65) { // A
        // Do your stuff
    }
})
```

This code is the same as your but on the entier DOM.

```
$('#input').val.indexOf('a')
```

This code will check if your field contains the letter A, can be the string 'abcd' or 'bar', etc.

If you want to check when the field loose the focus you can also you the event blur of jquery https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can disable keydown events when typing in an input field by checking if the event's target is an input field and doing nothing if it is.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
    return;
  }
  // Logic for keydown
});
```